# A simple jquery navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a navigation of text but rather than using serverside i want to use jquery and just write out the content once.

see sample image ....[image: Sample nav]

The nav bars will be the arrows at the bottom. If you get to the end turn the arrow to white or if you're starting make the left arrow white.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what have you got so far? or do you want someone to do it all for you?

Comment: what should the arrows do ? change the texts?

Comment: I'm by no means a js person, i've done it with serverside and it works just wanted a js elegant solution.

Comment: The arrows will move to the next item until it gets to the end similar to a Previous and Next item. Thanks

Comment: man those are some _serious_ design requirements... :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery solution will depend on how you want the navigation to work.  Do you want to replace the text? Do you want to scroll between items? There isn't much to work with here...

But, to get you started here is a "duck-tape" way of doing it... (Note: This is a not-pretty 'getting started' way of doing it, so plan to research better solutions down the line.)

```
var current = '1';
$('.navR').click(function (e) {  //When user clicks on the Right nav button...
    if (current == '1') { // If you are going to the first bit of new content...
        $('#content').replaceWith("<div id='content'>Your First Content Here...</div>");  //Replace the content with...
        current++;
            $('.navR').css('color','red'); // Make the Right arrow red when more content is left

    } else if (current == '2'){ // If you are going to the second bit of new content ....
        $('#content').replaceWith("<div id='content'>Your Second Content Here...</div>"); // Replace the content with....
        current++;
            $('.navR').css('color','white'); // Turn arrow White on last item
    };

});
```

And then reverse it for the left.

```
$('.navL').click(function (e) {
    if (current == '2') {
        $('#content').replaceWith("<div id='content'>Your First Content Here...</div>");
        current--;
            $('.navL').css('color','red'); 

    } else if (current == '1'){
        $('#content').replaceWith("<div id='content'>Your Second Content Here...</div>");
        current--;
            $('.navL').css('color','white'); 
    };

});
```

Again, this is a painfully simple and clumsy way of doing it, but maybe it will get you started...

Comment: Thanks for the great effort but thats just fiddly i guess my lack of js won't even make/let me comprehend. I appreciate the time you've put into this. I saw this[link] (http://bxslider.com/) a couple of hours ago, looks simple to use. Time will tell Cheers